# how can I print key and value form list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

how can I print key and id from the following in python

```
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-22158', id=u'566935'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-22135', id=u'566480'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-22131', id=u'566361'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-21850', id=u'561948'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-20967', id=u'533908'>,
 ]
```

more information about the project.
I am trying to use jira api calls and as an example get list of issues created by a certain user:

```
    from jira import JIRA
    from getpass import getpass
    from pprint import pprint 
    import csv

    def main():
        options = {
            'server': 'https://staging-jira.engsrv.mobileiron.com/',
        'verify': False
        }
        password = getpass()
        jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('hhaddadian', password))

        # Get the mutable application properties for this server (requires
        # jira-system-administrators permission)
        # props = jira.application_properties()

        # Find all issues reported by the admin
        issues = jira.search_issues('assignee=hhaddadian')
        pprint (issues) 
        for items in issues:
            print items 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and my result looks like this
[

```
root@localhost ~]# python test.py 
Password: 
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:838: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:838: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:838: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-22158', id=u'566935'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-22135', id=u'566480'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-22131', id=u'566361'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-21850', id=u'561948'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-20967', id=u'533908'>,
 ]
OPS-22158
OPS-22135
OPS-22131
OPS-21850
OPS-20967
```

I was wondering what kind of data I am getting in return. and how can I print key and id also maybe converting the result to a csv file.

Comment: also how can I convert this to csv.

Comment: You don't have a list of dictionaries, you have a list of unknown objects. If you want to get a proper answer you should update your question by providing us with more info about the objects.

Comment: I am using Jira api calls and want to get a list of issues created by a user

Comment: So update your question with the code. Specially the way you are creating this list and more info about the objects.

Comment: Try `pprint ([(item.key, item.id) for item in  issues])`.

Comment: If `key` and `id` are not your object attributes, you can use `dir(issues[0])` in order to see what kind of attributes your items have, then use a proper one in order to retrieve the intended attrs.

Comment: nice what kind of data am I getting? is it a list or dictionary?

Comment: What you mean by *nice*? :) dose the aforementioned snippet worked?

Comment: thank you for the information. the snippet worked.

Comment: 'JIRA_BASE_URL', '_IssueFields', '_READABLE_IDS', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_base_url', '_default_headers', '_get_url', '_load', '_options', '_parse_raw', '_resource', '_session', 'add_field_value', 'delete', 'expand', 'fields', 'find', 'id', 'key', 'permalink', 'raw', 'self', 'update']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import jira
# stuff

for issue in jira.search_issues('assignee=hhaddadian'):
    print(issue.fields.project.key)
```

The result of the jira.search_issues function is a list of Jira objects. These objects are defined here: https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

If you want the whole object (every field) in JSON format:

```
print(issue.raw)
```

Comment: thankx for the information. could you tell me how you founds fileds.project.key. I am trying to find the documentation but I couldnt find anything.

Comment: I googled 'python jira', the first link is the docs, and on the front page is a Quickstart guide that mentions the fields.project.key attribute.

Comment: for example issue.fileds would return this <class 'jira.resources.PropertyHolder'>
<class 'jira.resources.PropertyHolder'>
<class 'jira.resources.PropertyHolder'>

Comment: Use the .raw field instead - it should give you a list of EVERY field

Comment: I am using the same doc. but I cant find fields.project.key anywhere. :) and its really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

If you know key,values this is an easy way:

```
In [2]: dict_list = [{'key':'iman','value':21} , {'key': 'hooman', 'value' : 22}] #list of dictionaries

In [3]: for dict in dict_list: #dict = a dictionary of list
   ...:     print dict['key'], dict['value'] #key,values
   ...:     
iman 21
hooman 22
```